# Error:(72, 0) Gradle DSL method not found in Android 1.4

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

**Android 1.4**

**Error:(72, 0)** Gradle DSL method not found: 'android()'
Possible causes:The project 'My Project' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.

**href="openGradleSettings** Gradle settings  **The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.**

**href apply.gradle.plugin** Apply Gradle plugin

**And This is My Project Build.Gradle**

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
    }
}
allprojects {
    apply plugin: "eclipse"
    apply plugin: "idea"

    version = '1.0'
    ext {
        appName = 'Paddle'
        gdxVersion = '1.5.3'
        roboVMVersion = '1.0.0-beta-03'
        box2DLightsVersion = '1.3'
        ashleyVersion = '1.3.1'
        aiVersion = '1.5.0'
    }

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/" }
    }
}
project(":desktop") {
    apply plugin: "java"
dependencies {
    compile project(":core")
    compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-lwjgl:$gdxVersion"
    compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
    compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
}
}
project(":android") {
    apply plugin: "android"

    configurations { natives }

    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-android:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
        compile project(":BaseGameUtils")
        compile fileTree(dir: '../libs', include: '*.jar')
    }
}
project(":core") {
    apply plugin: "java"


    dependencies {
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion"
        compile fileTree(dir: '../libs', include: '*.jar')
    }
}
tasks.eclipse.doLast {
    delete ".project"
}
android {
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'
}
dependencies {
    compile files('libs/pushbots.2.0.8.jar')
    compile files('libs/tween-engine-api.jar')
    compile files('libs/tween-engine-api-sources.jar')
}
```

Comment: move android code block to project ":android"

Answer (score 0):

The android DSL comes from `jcenter()` not `mavenCentral()`

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
    }
}
```